# Kinect problems with matlab

Tags: windows, matlab, kinect

I am trying to use Kinect (the oldest one, the very first one released by Windows) and connect it to Matlab R2013b in a Windows 10 running laptop.

I've already followed the suggested steps and installed the Matlab Support package called "Kinect for Windows Runtime". This is supposed to instal the drivers needed to run the kinect on windows too.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF9AR.jpg)

However, as I use the command "imaqhwinfo", I get a warning saying that kinect is either not supported or no powered and this output:

```
      AdaptorDllVersion: '8.2 (R2013b)'
      AdaptorName: 'kinect'
        DeviceIDs: {1x0 cell}
       DeviceInfo: [1x0 struct]
```

I'd really appreciate if anyone could tell me what the error is or, tell me the configuration you used if you were able to use matlab and kinect.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is the kinect installed and can be used in other applications?

Comment: I didn't try to use it with any other application. Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think that Kinect v2.0 is already running with WIndows 10... That's the main issue I think.